# The output is list of numbers instead of one number

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, output, runge-kutta

I ran into the problem, I am new with this kind of usage of Python, I hope some one helps me in this issue.
I have a code using RungeKutta algorithm.
As I do `print(vH)`, it prints:

```
[70, 98.72259439054349, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How could I juts have `98.72259439054349` in out put when I write `print(vH)`?
This is the RungeKutta part of the code and `nrk=300`. Using `nrk` we have accurate out put, but with this code as you see we have `300` zeros in output.

```
def rk4(dH_func, H0, A, B, alpha, b, rho_de0, rho_dm0, z0, z1, nrk):

        if dH_func != False and drho_dm_func != False and drho_de_func != False :
           vH = [0] * (nrk + 1)

           h = (z1 - z0) / float(nrk)
           vH[0] = H = H0

           for i in range(1, nrk + 1):
               k1_H = h * dH_func(z, H, rho_de, rho_dm)

               k2_H = h * dH_func(z + 0.5 * h, H + 0.5 * k1_H, rho_de + 0.5 * k1_rho_de, rho_dm + 0.5 * k1_rho_dm)

               k3_H = h * dH_func(z + 0.5 * h, H + 0.5 * k2_H, rho_de + 0.5 * k2_rho_de, rho_dm + 0.5 * k2_rho_dm)

               k4_H = h * dH_func(z + h, H + k3_H, rho_de + k2_rho_de, rho_dm + k2_rho_dm)

               vH[i] = H = H + (k1_H + k2_H + k2_H + k3_H + k3_H + k4_H) / 6

               return vH
```

Comment: `print(vH[1])` like that

Comment: You `return` *in* the `for` loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Once I want to bring `return` out of loop, Python does not accept

Comment: @Ehsan: what error do you get? Perhaps you mixed tabs and spaces, because this is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you write:

```
for i in range(1, nrk + 1):
    # ...
    return vH
```

So that means that *at the end of the first iteration*, you immediately return the result.

If you want the function to return the result *after* all the iterations are done, you should write the `return vH` *outside* the body of the `for` loop, like:

```
for i in range(1, nrk + 1):
    # ...
return vH
```

If you only want to print the *second* item, you should print it with:

```
print(vH[1])
```

Comment: `[70, 98.72259439054349, 144.72020358361797, 215.66663177218655, 269.9988586813829, 269.9988586813829, 269.9988586813829, .....` the result

Comment: @Ehsan: if you only want the second element, you should print it like `print(vH[1])`.

Comment: it could be used as a regular number in other calculation automatically? I mean ` ans=vH[1]` and I use `ans` in all next calculations.

Comment: @Ehsan: yes, you obtain the second element, and can treat it as an indpendent one (well it is an independent one :)

Comment: and final question, as I did what you said to bring out the `return` out of loop, why the outputs has changed?`70, 98.72259439054349, 144.72020358361797, 215.66663177218655, 269.9988586813829`

Comment: @Ehsan: the point is that it is strange to define a list of 300 elements, and only fill the first two. In software design the idea is that functions are independent elements, that each solve a specific task, with not much "influence" of the specific use case, or other functions.

Comment: Because I am wondering the, which one of those numbers is my final answer then?! when I get the `return` out of loop.

Comment: @Ehsan: well you get the *list* out of the loop, so you can call the function, and then retrieve the proper element, for example `rk4(dH_func, H0, A, B, alpha, b, rho_de0, rho_dm0, z0, z1, nrk)[1]` (with the paramters filled in)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.